# The custom icons I created and imported to flutter are rendering as Chinese characters in the app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I used [fluttericon](https://www.fluttericon.com/) to make some custom icons and use them in my project, I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/flutterpub/how-to-use-custom-icons-in-flutter-834a079d977) and whenever I use the icons that I downloaded a Chinese a character comes up instead of the icon like [this](https://imgur.com/gallery/Wom6jmR) . I tried the solutions in github/stackoverflow but none of them worked. there is no problems when running flutter doctor and the path to the font is correct.

here is the code snippet:

```
Row(
children: <Widget>[
Icon(MyFlutterApp.droplet),
Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7.0),
child: Text(
'Do you have diabetes?',
style: TextStyle(
fontSize: 19.0,
),
),
),
```

and here is the pubspec.yaml file

```
name: flutter_auth
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
intl_phone_field: ^1.4.2
http: ^0.12.2
shared_preferences: ^0.5.12
toast: ^0.1.5
horizontal_picker: ^1.0.0
numberpicker: ^1.2.1
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
flutter_svg: ^0.19.0
eva_icons_flutter:

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.8.0"
flutter_icons:
image_path: "assets/images/bg.png"
android: true
ios: true

flutter:
uses-material-design: true

assets:
- assets/images/
- assets/icons/
fonts:
- family: MyFlutterApp
fonts:
- asset: fonts/MyFlutterApp.ttf
```

Comment: Try to rebuild it, Sometimes hot reload won't work.

Comment: Totally rebuilding helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the indentation in the pubspec.yaml at uses-material-design

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
  fonts:
    - family:  MyFlutterApp
      fonts:
       - asset: fonts/MyFlutterApp.ttf
```